# Is it possible to put a comment on a code in github public repository

Tags: github

A public Github repository belongs to one of my fellow developers. I need to put comments on certain areas of code. I have done this previously using pull requests 
Is there a way to do it without opening a pull request and directly commenting on the code?
I don't see an option as of now. Not sure if the other developer needs to add me or grant certain permissions

Comment: Have you been added as a collaborator of the repository?

Comment: @HuyPhạm Nopes I am not added as a collaborator

Comment: I don't know but I can't even add a comment on my code in my own public repo